# With VBA, copying a range with format 12.3456 by refering to that range results in 12,3456.(COMMAS instead of DOTS)

Tags: excel, text, format, copy, range

Help, I am a reasonable expierenced Visual Basic user, my question seems very simple, but I just can't get it to work.

From my worksheet I want to copy a column filled with project numbers with the format 12.3456 (##.####) by refering to that column. Below mentioned example has the project numbers with this format in range A2:A100, and I want to copy them to range B2:B100

range("B2:B100") = range("A2:A100").value

Seems simple so far, but when I do this, the format of the project numbers changes to 12,3456 (##,####). Notice that the 'DOTS' have been replaced by 'COMMAS', so the format has been changed to a value. Please try it for yourselves with some fictional project numbers in this format (you must change the format of column A:A to text). I have tried a number of things like using the format function, and stuff like changing the format of the source & destination range. But it keeps changing the format of the project numbers to a value.

In order to not slow down the file I would highly prefer to avoid the copy and paste function of VBA, and for the same reason I would also prefer to avoid the loop function.

I'm am really stuck on something that shouldn't be so hard to do, so your suggestions would be highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Just to check, you did try using [`Range.NumberFormat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.numberformat) then? Did you set the format of column B to Text before the value transfer?

Comment: You could always try to `PasteSpecial`.

Comment: Maybe just change the decimal separator on File>Options>Advanced?